# wrdDoc.SaveAs(SaveToFile); not working in windows 8

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-8.1, delphi-7, office-2010

I have developed an app for computers a while back, that generates a word document and saves it automatically under a name provided by the software.

The application has worked perfectly in windows xp and windows 7. But now it needed to be moved to a windows 8.1 computer and since the generating works perfectly. But the save command `wrdDoc.SaveAs(SaveToFile);` does not work.

Basically what happens, is on that command's execution a save dialog appears and you can save the document yourself. After you click save. You get an error `command failed` with no further details.

Is there anything that has changed since windows 7 that prevents this code from executing properly?

The old computer used the following:
windows 7
office 2007/2010/2013(all were used at some point in time)

New computer:
windows 8.1
office 2010

**UPDATE:**
it is also worth noting, the dialog does not show any of the word documents in the folder if i browse there... Can this be a hint to the problem?

**Resolved**

I managed to find the problem. It's a brand new laptop, and Acer had a bunch of crap installed that sync's with office and explore. Once i uninstalled that the software returned to working normally...

Thank you guys anyway so much :)

Comment: Should work fine on Win 8. You'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am busy reworking the application in Delphi XE5, but in the mean time this application cannot be edited... The Delphi 7 installation for some reason does not work... I cannot go into the code other than in XE5. But obviously it is the environment around the application that is the only change. So i believe the problem then must lie there?

Comment: And D7 & XE5 are not compatible. So to edit the code in xe5 will take days of changes to get it to compile...

Comment: I don't really understand any of that. I understood that the only difference was the os. Now you tell us you changed the os and the compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No what I meant was i cannot change the application to help with debugging. So the only change was in the OS... Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: @Marcel In what location is the file being saved in Windows 8? Maybe the user does not have permission to save/write to that location.

Comment: @DaleM the file is being saved in a sub directory in C... But using the dialog i can save there. I have also run the application as administrator and same thing happens...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your word version. Only 2007 has a "Saveas" method for the document object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221597%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The later versions (2010 and 2013) only have a "Saveas2" Method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836084.aspx)